# Creating a circular progress bar

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I want to make circular progress bar and found this [tutorial](http://timokorinth.de/creating-circular-progress-bar-wpf-silverlight/)

But after I added the code to my project and and the class example I can see my panel but there are no circles in it. I have the same code as in the code example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="530,303,114,303">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="8" Percentage="100" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="#026873" StrokeThickness="8" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Radius="15" StrokeThickness="20" SegmentColor="#FF878889" Percentage="100" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" StrokeThickness="25" SegmentColor="#026873" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="38" SegmentColor="#FF878889" Percentage="100" Radius="19" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" StrokeThickness="38" SegmentColor="#026873" Radius="19" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="#026873" StrokeThickness="25" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="White" StrokeThickness="2" Radius="20" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="White" StrokeThickness="2" />
        <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" SegmentColor="White" StrokeThickness="2" Radius="30" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
<Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" Value="20" Width="200" Margin="597,185,227,495" />
```

Comment: This blog only explain some codes. But you copy this code and trying to use. This is wrong. You download full code from bottom of the this blog.

Comment: OK after download this code this works fine but the only thing that i cannot find is how make this circle bigger

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Please see my new question and my new update.